# array members of structs in dart:ffi

Tags: c++, c, dart, dart-ffi

I'd like to use Bob Jenkins rng in my flutter projects
https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html

here we have a struct with 2 static buffers in it

```
/* context of random number generator */
struct randctx
{
  ub4 randcnt;
  ub4 randrsl[RANDSIZ];
  ub4 randmem[RANDSIZ];
  ub4 randa;
  ub4 randb;
  ub4 randc;
};
typedef  struct randctx  randctx;
```

now in dart:ffi a Struct class can only have members of int, double and Pointer, decorated appropriately.
However, I can't describe this struct with given NativeTypes.

```
class _Rand_context extends Struct {
  @Uint32()
  int counter;
  Pointer<Uint32> result;
  Pointer<Uint32> mem;
  @Uint32()
  int a;
  @Uint32()
  int b;
  @Uint32()
  int c;
}
```

because `ctx.result.asTypedList(256)` crashes. So what I did is simply change the arrays in the struct to pointers and initialize this way:

```
randctx* create_context() {
  randctx* ctx = (randctx*)malloc(sizeof(randctx));
  ub4* mem = (ub4*)malloc(sizeof(ub4) * RANDSIZ);
  ub4* res = (ub4*)malloc(sizeof(ub4) * RANDSIZ);
  ctx->randa=ctx->randb=ctx->randc=(ub4)0;
  memset(res, 0, sizeof(ub4) * RANDSIZ);
  memset(mem, 0, sizeof(ub4) * RANDSIZ);
  ctx->randmem = mem;
  ctx->randrsl = res;
  randinit(ctx, TRUE);

  return ctx;
}
```

This can be handled by `asTypedList` but I'm not familiar how the GC handles structs, I'm worried that mem and result won't get free'd up. Is this the case? Or how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with something:
keep the original struct but add 2 extra pointers for the buffers

```
struct randctx
{
  ub4 randcnt;
  ub4 randrsl[RANDSIZ];
  ub4 randmem[RANDSIZ];
  ub4* rslptr;
  ub4* memptr;
  ub4 randa;
  ub4 randb;
  ub4 randc;
};
typedef  struct randctx  randctx;

randctx* create_context() {
  randctx* ctx = (randctx*)malloc(sizeof(randctx));
  ctx->randa=ctx->randb=ctx->randc=(ub4)0;
  memset(ctx->randrsl, 0, sizeof(ub4) * RANDSIZ);
  memset(ctx->randmem, 0, sizeof(ub4) * RANDSIZ);
  ctx->memptr = ctx->randmem;
  ctx->rslptr = ctx->randrsl;
  randinit(ctx, TRUE);

  return ctx;
}
```

and provide the pointers to `asTypedList`. Seems to work, things are in one place and hopefully, there are no dangling ownerships. Can live with the extra 16 bytes.